# Policy control for VPN on Android on WSO2 EMM

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

Is it possible to control the VPN settings on EMM policy on version 2.0.1?
According to this the answer is no:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/EMM+Policy+Settings
According to this you can:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM210/Setting+Up+a+VPN+Policy+on+Android+Devices

What am i missing?

If it isn't possible, does anyone know when it will be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, notice the EMM version on the top of the page of both pages you sent,

https://docs.wso2.com/display/**EMM201**/EMM+Policy+Settings - This is for EMM 2.0.1

https://docs.wso2.com/display/**EMM210**/Setting+Up+a+VPN+Policy+on+Android+Devices - This is for EMM 2.1.0 which is the upcoming version of EMM. That is why it says on top the page is work in progress.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so please mark it.